# Email Sending from Local Server in PHP

Tags: php

I have my file mail.php :

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("syedsamiruddin29@gmail.com", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<form method='post' action='mail.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

but when i run it. i get this error :

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "127.0.0.1" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\safepay247\mail.php on line 13
Thank you for using our mail form
```

what im trying to do is to send an email to my email id : syedsamiruddin29@gmail.com using php to the person's email written in the input type.

Ive gone through many videos but none help me solve the php.ini problem.

Comment: You usually don't want to send mail from a development server - it won't arrive in most cases if it's sent from a dynamic IP. What kind of server are you on with this? Who is administering it?

Comment: @Pekka - im using easyPHP as my local server.

Comment: I would recommend using swiftmailer(http://swiftmailer.org/) instead of the mail() function. In your case, the cause of your error is that you do not have a valid SMTP server set up in your `php.ini`.

Comment: Why do you want to send E-Mails from it in the first place? Is it a live server, who is administering it?

Comment: @phpdev - yea i know. how do i solve it if i wud opt to use php's mail() function :)

Comment: @Pekka - im going to implement it in a website of mine which is ready n working. i jus have to add a function in the registering form which would send an email activation link to the user on successfull registration.

Comment: But where will the site be running in the end? On that server?

Comment: @Pekka - yea on that server :)

Comment: All this is to make testings with a local server, right? but for production, should I keep almost same code and just change (in the «php.ini» file) the SMTP = // instead of localhost, will I put the smtp address of my remote server? is it like that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your SMTP server in your `php.ini`.

The directives you need to change are listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php). The settings should be provided by your hosting provider.

But before we get ahead of ourselves, just a quick warning:

- You are sending the email by masquerading as someone else by setting the Email in the "from" header.
- Most SMTP server would require some form of authentication, for example to send something using the gmail SMTP server, I would need to authenticate with my username and password.
- If the email in the form field does not match the authentication username, it could be rejected by the server, or it could be changed to reflect the authentication username. Finally, it might not play well with spam filters.

My suggestion is that you send the email from one of your own email accounts, for example (customerenquiry@yourdomain.com). Then in the body of the message, put in the customer's email address. You can also set the `reply-to` header to the customer's email address, so that clicking "reply to" in your email client would automatically put their email address in the "to" field.

Comment: yes i can do that but how do i change my php.ini file ? i mean what do i have to change in it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open the `php.ini`.
2. Search for the attribute called `SMTP` in the php.ini file. Generally you can find the line `SMTP=localhost`. change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP. And the set the port of 25.

   ```
   SMTP = smtp.gmail.com #user your smtp address here
   smtp_port = 25
   ```
3. Restart the apache server or wamp or xammp. Whatever you are using.
4. Now try to send the mail using the mail() function

Comment: im getting this error : Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. gl4sm17489588obb.23 in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\safepay247\mail.php on line 13
Thank you for using our mail form

Comment: @DaveJarvis, It is not arrogance :P